# Can NSIS be used to package MSI installers?

Tags: windows-installer, package, nsis

I have two MSI installers for 32 bit and 64 bit platforms, and I'd like to create a single installer to ship that will run the appropriate MSI based on the platform it's being run on. I appreciate that this is not possible with MSI alone.

The package required is very simple, just check the bit-ness of the platform it's running on and launch the appropriate MSI, but I haven't yet found any *free* tools that will do this. I've come across NSIS, which looks promising, does anyone know if it is appropriate for this task?

Comment: [Early research](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers) looks positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [x64.nsh](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Include/x64.nsh) to detect the platform and then extract & execute. Something like this:

```
!include x64.nsh
Section
Initpluginsdir
${If} ${RunningX64}
  File "/oname=$pluginsdir\inst.msi" "myfiles\amd64.msi"
${Else}
  File "/oname=$pluginsdir\inst.msi" "myfiles\x86.msi"
${EndIf}
ExecWait '"msiexec" /i "$pluginsdir\inst.msi"'
SectionEnd
```